# using Linq To Sql to save to an SDF (local database file) in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sdf

HI, I am trying to save some data to my .sdf file using a LinqToSql object.
I have a table as follows -

```
PersonId int not null pk
forename nvarchar(4000)
surname nvarchar(4000)
Birthdate DateTime
IsMale bit
Biography nvarchar(4000)
```

I am inserting a value into all fields apart from the PersonId column (set to identity, increment).

I am using the C# code of

```
myLinqToSqlObject.Persons.InsertOnSubmit(thisPerson);
```

then

```
 thisDataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

and i get the exception of "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."
and an inner exception of just "Varchar"

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks

EDIT - Showing code to populate thisPerson

```
thisPerson.Forename = thisDlg.Forename;
thisPerson.Surname = thisDlg.Surname;
thisPerson.Biography = thisDlg.Biography;
thisPerson.IsMale = thisDlg.IsMale;
thisPerson.BirthDate = thisDlg.BirthDate;
```

Where all fields return a value (no null values)

Comment: Can you show the code that you're using to populate thisPerson?

Answer (score 1):

The DataContext has a Log property; if you assign a StreamWriter to it to write to a file, or attached Console.Out, it will write the SQL generated by the context, and you can better debug the query then potentially...

Also, to figure out what's going on, before submitting the changes, call context.GetChangeSet(),and use the immediate window and VS debugging to see what resides within this collection (it has the inserts, updates, and deletes being performed).

That will help you get to the answer quicker...

Comment: Thanks @Brian, how do i write it out to the console?

Answer (score 0):

To create SDF file to DBML Using Visual Studio 2010 than, Write below line in visual studio 2010 command prompt than Enter and Execute it.

```
SqlMetal.exe "EnterFilePath\CloudKase.sdf" /dbml:"EnterFilePath\CloudKase.dbml"
```

Also this SDF and DBML file in used in Visual Studio 2012 Easy to Access and Implement the code.

Happy Coding :)